# How do I remove TFS connections from a Visual Studio 2010 C# project/solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, project, solution

I have been given the full source code to work on locally (C#.NET/XAML/Visual Studio 2010), but I do not have access to TFS.

Every time I open the solution, it always asks for TFS which I have to cancel every time, but the code is now developed locally from here on out and I will not have access.

How do I effectively "disconnect" TFS from this build?

Comment: I created a VSIX addon that removes TFS bindings and zips up a copy of your solution (also removes all unnecessary files). See http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb5d5d7d-f67e-4076-8fd0-23f36976deff

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either choose to work offline, or unbind the projects:

File->Source Control->Change Source Control

Comment: What if it's already unbound, and it still tries to connect to TFS? Because I had this problem.

Answer (score 4):

File>Source Control>Change Source Control...>Unbind

Beaten to it...

Answer (score 3):

If solution is already unbound (which happens sometimes), you can simply open the solution file, or the project file in notepad, and delete information regarding connecting to TFS.

In solution files (`.sln` files) for example, you might see information like this:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 4
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = https://nemati.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = ..\\Framework\\Framework\\Framework.csproj
    SccProjectName1 = ../Framework/Framework
    SccLocalPath1 = ..\\Framework\\Framework
    SccProjectUniqueName2 = Website\\Phis.csproj
    SccProjectName2 = Website
    SccLocalPath2 = Website
    SccProjectUniqueName3 = Tests\\Tests.csproj
    SccProjectName3 = Tests
    SccLocalPath3 = Tests
EndGlobalSection
```

Just read it, and you'll understand what it says. Very simple, self-descriptive and self-explanatory. Just delete this section and reopen your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found was to go **Tools > Options** Then, under the left hand menu select "*Source Control*".

You should see a "*Current source control plug-in:"* dropdown menu on the right hand side. Select "**None**" and please do this while no projects are open.

Doing it this way makes it easy if you ever wanted to learn TFS.